# What happens when an end-user accesses a PHP file that is being overwritten at the same time?

Tags: php, apache

I am creating a release process for deploying newly modified PHP files to a production server. I would like to know what happens when an end-user accesses the PHP web page at exactly the same time that it is being overwritten during a release.

Are there any best practices for releasing web scripts and code that account for any problems that can occur in the above scenario?

Comment: I think this kind of scenario will be handled by the webserver OS, or even http server itself, since this is very common.

Comment: Reminds me of java threads Dead locks. you can lock threads and same way i think you can put mechanism which locks your file until user is reading and that way you can have some control over your process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like to know what happens when an end-user accesses the PHP web page at exactly the same time that it is being overwritten during a release.

Depends whether or not the file has been completely overwritten already. If not completely written, PHP would try to parse the incomplete file which normally leads to an error.

> Are there any best practices for releasing web scripts and code that account for any problems that can occur in the above scenario?

you can do a lot of things, like preventing access as long as you update stuff (by displaying a maintenance page) or by having multiple versions of the codebase next to each other and the ability to switch one version live via file-system (symlinks) or server configuration.

Answer (score 1):

There are two scenarios:

- The user starts reading before the writing of the file begins
- The user starts reading after the writing of the file begins

In the first scenario, the user will usually reads the old file (but this may vary with different filesystems). Note though that you may change multiple files which includes each other, and in that case the user may incompatible versions of the files (e.g., one file from version 1.1 which all of a sudden includes a file from version 1.2).

In the other scenario the user will read a partial file, as hakre describes.

There are FTP servers which uploads the entire file under a temporary name and then renames it when it's fully uploaded.

There are ways to avoid these problems entirely, for example by closing the site during uploading. If you have a loadbalanced environemtn you can take down one server after the other and make the upgrades in offline mode without closing the website.